# inputAccessoryView with custom view hide After I Dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, inputaccessoryview

First of all , my project is so structured:

-home page with a tableView to add element

-floating Button: when clicked make appear keyboard with above a custom view (and inside a textView) to digit input

Now, I have a problem with inputAccessoryView and dismiss keyboard:

I have used inputAccessoryView to move a custom view above the keyboard like this:

```
MytextView.inputAccessoryView= MyContainerView;
```

And this work correctly.

My problem occur when I dismiss keyboard using:

```
[MytextView resignFirstResponder];
```

The keyboard and relative inputView disappear properly but After when I try again to make MytextView the firstResponder does not work (the keyboard not appear).

I hypothesize that occurs because textView is hide with inputAccessoryView under the screen and inputAccessoryView change The inizial position of textview (Initial in the Middle of the screen); so textView is not focusable and keyboard not appear when I use:

```
[MyTextView becomeFirstResponder]
```

Is there a way to reposition programmatically the textView to initial position (middle of the screen) so can become focusable when I call becomeFirstResponder?

Or is there a way to fix inputAccessoryView in the safe area when i dismiss keyboard?

(Sorry , I’m New to objective-c and IOS)

Thanks!

Comment: What you do sounds correct. The keyboard that does not appear - is this on the simulator? Also check on a device. The simulator by default connects to your computer keyboard and then often hides the popup device keyboard. So also check those simulator settings.

Comment: @skaak I have tried on my IPhone XR so that there is no problem with computer keyboard; I tried also on simulator ( Before selecting on I/O -> toggle keyboard)  only the device keyboard is selected and not computer keyboard. The problem is probably relative to MyTextView that change position (because of inputAccessoryView) and is not focusable in the safe area when I try again to call becomeFirstResponder on It.

Comment: Also, I have researched a lot on this and am sure what I mentioned above is the problem; Now, the real problem is how to make the textview focusable after the dismissal of the keyboard (For example, changing the position of MyTextView at the bottom programmatically ) because MyTextView is hidden with inputAccessoryView under the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me jump out of the comments to have more freedom. Based on your description you could do something like this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    super.viewDidLoad;
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector( keyboardDidHide: )
                           name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                         object:nil];
}

- ( void ) keyboardDidHide:( NSNotification * ) notification
{
... do stuff here...
}
```

Then you can reposition or do whatever you need in there.  Alternatively, you can also listen for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and do preparatory stuff there. In fact, there is a whole family of `UIKeyboard...` notifications that you could use this way and I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Here is something else, if you ever need to reposition based on the keyboard size.

```
- ( void ) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary * info = notification.userInfo;
    CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

... do stuff with kbRect ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW I have had a vaguely similar problem once and would adjust constraints when the keyboard hide / showed to change the size of something in response to it (the keyboard) being visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

to dismiss the input view?

I never get any issue to set any input to firstResponder after I trigger that code.