# Best solution for up view over keyboards

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im new in IOS, and i some confusion. I have hierarchy like this

[image]

tableView - contains my list of item
PlayerMessagePanel - this is a panel for send a message. But when i click to UITextField in the `PlayerMessagePanel the keyboard completely covers everything.

I tried to do like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

then listeners add margins

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
    //Keyboard becomes visible
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.view.frame.origin.y - 220,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height);   //move up
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
    //keyboard will hide
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.view.frame.origin.y + 220,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height);   //move down
}
```

but it didnt work correct, like this

[image]

please give to me some advice how i need to do. Thanks

Comment: Use the storyboard and add a constraint to the bottom of the Player Message Panel. Then link or drag that constraint into your interface, just like you do with other things on storyboard. Then, when that notification ```keyboardDidShow``` fire, change the constraints constant and set it back to e.g. 0 when the other one fires.

Comment: Also look at this ... there is an example to get the size of the keyboard from the notification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094204/inputaccessoryview-with-custom-view-hide-after-i-dismiss-keyboard/63098230#63098230